# use wordpress hooks inside static method

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I have divided my Wordpress custom theme functions file into some objects that will be responsible to load all the assets and various theme mod. I need a way to instantiate the class methods inside a static function that will be used only to call the Wordpress hooks.

I've tried the following code but without success:

```
class Theme_Assets_Loader {

  public static function init()
  {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array('Theme_Assets_Loader', '_css') );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array('Theme_assets_Loader', '_scripts') );
  }
}
```

The `_css` and `_scripts` methods are used to load css and javascripts files.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Is this class within a namespace? If those methods exist, add at least empty definitions for those in your question.

Comment: @yivi no namespace, I want to call from the static method, other methods that are within the same class, the static method will be responsable to call wordpress hooks